# How to send a POST request using an html button

Tags: javascript, html, grafana, influxdb

I want to send a POST request to the URL, for example, I want to create a database in influxdb by pressing this button.
So far I tried this but cannot make it work

```
 <button id="post-btn">Post</button>

<script> 
const button = document.getElementById('post-btn');
button.addEventListener('click', async _ => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://00.00.000.000:2000/query', {
      method: 'post',
      body: {
       "q=create database telecom"
      }
    });
    console.log('Completed!', response);
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(Error: ${err});
  }
});
</script>
```

The error it gives me is "Failed to fetch"

Comment: What goes wrong then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deal with `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing`, so you need to allow your Grafana origin on the InfluxDB server side.

Anyway it looks very unsafe. If you can call `create database telecom`, then also other Grafana user can requests own queries, e.g. `drop database telecom`. Grafana should have read only access and InfluxDB should be managed outside of Grafana.